# Creating and using custom XML special characters with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have a `ColorFormat` class that stores basic information about a color format. The aim is to be able to serialize and deserialize to and from XML. To represent Red, Green and Blue I use special color string identifiers:

```
public const string RedColorIdentifier = "&red;";
public const string GreenColorIdentifier = "&green;";
public const string BlueColorIdentifier = "&blue;";
```

For a format like "#RGB", the class format string is as such:

```
colorFormat.Format = "#" + ColorFormat.RedColorIdentifier +
                           ColorFormat.GreenColorIdentifier +
                           ColorFormat.BlueColorIdentifier;
```

Ideally, the serialized XML should be:

```
<ColorFormat Name="HexFmt" ColorBase="Hex">#&red;&green;&blue;</ColorFormat>
```

The actual serialization is:

```
<ColorFormat Name="HexFmt" ColorBase="Hex">#&amp;red;&amp;green;&amp;blue;</ColorFormat>
```

I was wondering if there is a way of "serializing and deserializing" your own custom special XML character

Comment: You can use `CDATA` [CDATA Sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The XML `<ColorFormat Name="HexFmt" ColorBase="Hex">#&red;&green;&blue;</ColorFormat>` is not valid.  E.g. upload to http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will get an error ***Errors in the XML document:** 1: 50 The entity "red" was referenced, but not declared.*

Comment: `&text;` - is xml [entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition#Entity_declarations). Don't use entity like that. Use any other symbol instead of `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it, gotta implement IXmlSerializable as such:

```
public class ColorFormat : IXmlSerializable
{
    ...

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Name = reader.GetAttribute(nameof(Name));
        ColorBase = CommonUtil.ParseStringToEnum<NumberBase>(reader.GetAttribute(nameof(ColorBase)));
        Format = reader.ReadInnerXml();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString(nameof(Name), Name);
        writer.WriteAttributeString(nameof(ColorBase), ColorBase.ToString());
        writer.WriteRaw(Format);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CData` to wrap special characters.
From MSDN [CDATA Section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076(v=vs.110).aspx)

For example class below will be serialized witt color values wrapped with CData

```
[XmlType("ColorFormat")]
public class ColorFormat
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ColorBase { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Format { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public XmlNode[] SerializableFormat
    {
        get
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            return new XmlNode[] { doc.CreateCDataSection(this.Format) };
        }
        set
        {
            this.Format = value[0].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Using of `ColorFormat` class

```
const string FORMAT = "&red;&green;&blue;";

var format = new ColorFormat
{
    Name = "HexFormat",
    ColorBase = "Hex",
    Format = FORMAT
};

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ColorFormat));
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, format);
    Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
}
```

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus, I have changed `SerializableFormat` to be a `XmlNode[]` type and changed `XmlAnyElement` attribute to `XmlText`

Comment: yeah, works like magic. However am not too satisfied about it although it's a great answer. The CDATA adds too much complexity to the file, as it will be manually edited by normal pc users. I've seen a lead with custom entity  in XML, will have to explore a bit more